# Change Materialize primary color on WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, materialize

I included the Materialize library in WordPress.

```
function materialize_styles() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'materialize-js','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js', array(), '1.0', false);
wp_enqueue_style( 'materialize','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css', array(), '1.0', false );
}
```

I am getting the default pinkish color to all my elements as a result.
Is there a way to change the default color scheme without having to download the SASS files.

I am looking for a CSS way if possible.

Thank you all.

Comment: I don't think there is another way than just overwriting the existing styles in a separate file or using a "Custom CSS" plugin. Obviously you would need to overwrite the colors for each element separately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I already know this method. I was hoping for a initial setting in the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with materialize too, you need to create a CSS, SCSS or SASS file which overwrites original style of Materialize...

In *.css you need to write for exemple:

```
.dropdown-content li>a {
     color: #EE6E73 !important;
```

rembember `!important` at the end, it's necessary to replace original style